# osm map SLD for geoserver (shape files)

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver

I have downloaded OSM map in shape files from (`http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/nepal.html`) and I have multiple shape files like Roads, Building, landuse etc.

I want to publish this files in my geoserver, which I have no problem. I can easily do it. Now the problem is creating the SLD for each types. I have download various SLD available in Internet. But no Luck so far. Every time I use any of those SLD I can't view my layer. The error message looks like this:

> The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of landuse and the layer is: main:landuse

I have 4 columns in my attributes in shape file (fid,   osm_id,     name,   type).

And my SLD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>landuse_overlay</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>landuse_overlay</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>military</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/military_red_hz2.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.329</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff5555</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>nature_reserve</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </Filter>
          <MinScaleDenominator>50000</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/nature_reserve5.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#66cc33</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="strok-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#66cc33</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <VendorOption name="autoWrap">60</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>nature_reserve</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>50000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/nature_reserve6.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>      
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#66cc33</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>national_park</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>1000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#08a136</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">.3</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#66cc33</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>park</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>recreation_ground</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </Or>
          </Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="fill">#b6fdb6</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#66cc33</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="strok-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#66cc33</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <VendorOption name="autoWrap">60</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>quarry</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/quarry2.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.329</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#829495</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

     <Rule>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <PropertyName>landuse</PropertyName>
              <Literal>vineyard</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </Filter>
          <MinScaleDenominator>100000</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>750000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#abdf96</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <PropertyName>landuse</PropertyName>
              <Literal>vineyard</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>100000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/vineyard.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>orchard</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>250000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:href="/var/lib/geoserver_data/Test/rogue_symbols/orchard.png"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                </Graphic>
              </GraphicFill>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#abd190</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>industrial</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#beb8c1</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>landuse</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>reservoir</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#b5d0d0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>leisure</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>sports_centre</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>250000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#64c397</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here???

AJ

Answer (score 1):

The SLD style was designed to work against a OSM dump with a "landuse" attribute that your does not.
There are many ways to extract data from the raw OSM files, and they lead to different layer and attribute layouts, but a given SLD will work only against a specific one. 
You will have to either find SLDs that work against the structure of your shapefiles, or adapt the styles to use the attributes that you have

Comment: How do I find the SLD? or if I have to change the SLD I have what do I need to do?

Comment: In the first case, Google is your friend, in the second, you can learn about how to use SLD in the GeoServer guide: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/index.html